# trouble with getting data from web api and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I wrote database on Entity Framework Code First and i use it in my Web Api.
If i have more than 400 records in my table  ,i can`t get any records, 
but if i have less than 400 record everything works ok .  
This is my code for getting records :

```
 public IEnumerable<Contact> Get(int pageSize, int pageIndex)
    {

        return db.Set<Contact>().OrderBy(e => e.Id).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).AsParallel<Contact>().AsOrdered();
    }
```

Another method for getting 1 record doesnt work too.

```
public  Contact Get(int id) { return db.Set<Contact>().Find(id); }
```

And i notice with adding new records times for response increments.
When i have 100 record  time for response is 4 second,if i have 200 second 10 seconds.

 Can you explain what i am doing wrong ?

**EDIT:** code from controller

```
    private ICompanyService companyService;
    public CompaniesController(ICompanyService companyService)
    {
        this.companyService = companyService;
    }
    //// GET api/companies
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]int SizePage=100, [FromUri]int Page=1)
    {
        return Ok(companyService.Get(SizePage, Page));
    }
    //// GET api/companies/5 
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]int id)
    {
        return Ok(companyService.Get(id));
    }
```

Comment: whats the error? Or are there no errors? And what `pageSize` and `pageIndex` did you provide.

Comment: There are not errors, pageSize by default  is 100 and pageIndex is 0.

Comment: @IvanMartinyuk why are you using Skip(0)?

Comment: yeah thats my stupit mistake, but even i try get 1 record from this method code:  public virtual Contact Get(int id)
        {
            return db.Set<Contact>().Find(id);
        } , controler doesn`t return value.

Comment: Please provide the code for the controller

Comment: `code`
        private ICompanyService companyService;

        public CompaniesController(
            ICompanyService companyService)
        {
            this.companyService = companyService;
        }


        //// GET api/companies/5
        public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]int id)
      {
            return Ok(companyService.Get(id));
            
        }`code`

Comment: Skip 0 is not a problem and is correct for the first page. It might be something with the `AsParallel()` method, try to play around with that.

Comment: @CularBytes yes it could be, but another method which i use doesnt have AsParallel(), but it does not return any response too.

Comment: I'm sorry Ivan, but it seems that something else is going on that we don't know. The code looks ok and if it really makes a difference between 399 and 400 records than I don't know what to do either (assuming same page and pagesize). I don't know what `db` is in your code, but normally one would do: `using(DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext()) { db.Contacts.... }` Thats all I have.

Comment: Probably response timeout become your issue. Try inserting `((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout` on your context constructor section, and debug suspected methods. If it still doesn't work, change your DB engine settings to make sure.